# Not able to enable postgres for php 7.1

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5.3, laravel-valet

I want to enable the `postgres` and I am not able to.

To make sure `postgres` is installed on my mac I ran the command `postgres -V` and I can see `postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1` as an out put so that confirms postgres is installed.

I ran the command `php -v` and the out i see is `PHP 7.1.0`.

Looking at the `phpinfo` I opened the `.ini` file and un commented the following two from it.

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

and I still do not see postgres in my `phpinfo` however I see the following warning in console.

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0_11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0_11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_pgsql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0_11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pgsql.dll'
>   - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0_11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pgsql.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

I am setting up [laravel valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet), every project seems to be working perfectly fine with mysql but any project that is using postgres throws the error

> DriverException in AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 91:
>   An exception
>   occured in driver: could not find driver

From command line I am able to connect with the database using the command `psql databasename` and run any query so I am not sure what the problem is.

I will really appreciate any help on what I am missing.

**Update 1**

I commented the the following two in phpini and atleast the warning went away on terminal however i still cant get the postgres to work.

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

Comment: As far as I know, DLL's are not for Mac OS X; rather, they're for Windows. As a result, you need to acquire the Mac equivalent of a DLL (.dylib?) and load those.

Comment: can you please elaborate how to do that?

Comment: https://php-osx.liip.ch/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating PHP to version 7.1.5.